# Problems in Net connectivity

Tags: networking

I have installed both Ubuntu Raring Ringtail and Windows7 in my computer (dual-boot). While all the sites can be visited using Windows, some sites like Yahoo! can't be accessed using Ubuntu. I can't understand how to solve this problem. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this happened, but the problem stopped as soon as I installed a proprietary driver. Does anyone have a clue about why the system hung up in the first place and why it stopped?